# Mobile app to launch as website

Tags: android, ios, webview, hyperlink, mobile-browser

Is it possible to create a cross-platform mobile app that will launch as a website(in default browser)?
I am writing a fully responsive web portal project on MVC.
and when I finish I want to make a mobile app that will open that website link (in default browser) when launched on the device.
IS there a very simple way?

Comment: I in the online it self there are some sites are there. If you give the url they generate APK file. If you Install that apk that will open your site only.

Comment: can you name these sites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case your only requirement is to show your website in mobile then you can use any cross platform technologies like ReactNative, Xamarin, PhoneGap to open webView when the app is launched and load this URL which doesn't take much time.

**Word of caution:**
But loading web view in just web view is not recommended approach. Mobile development has its own advantages over webview. Native frameworks will always have their own mark on their own platforms. The **look and feel and performance** definitely becomes the distinguishable point here. I suggest going with technology like **ReactNative** which absolutely takes all advantages of native frameworks and works as cross-platform.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can try WebView from React Native. Here is its code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {WebView} from 'react-native';

export default class MyWeb extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <WebView
        source={{uri: "https://stackoverflow.com/users/10118612/abdul-karim-khan"}}
        style={{marginTop: 20}}
      />
    );
  }
}
```